# Up-votes indicator on user profile page displays hand cursor

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, design

User profile page has two numbers - number of times user up-voted and number of times user down-voted. Each of these two numbers is decorated with up/down arrows. Down arrow for `up-votes` number has this html code: `<span class="vote-down-off" style="cBursor:default"></span>`. This **cBursor** leads to a hand cursor when hovering this arrow while there is no way to manipulate it anyhow. Is it a typo?

Comment: Nice catch... :)

Comment: *This cBursor leads to a hand cursor* — more precisely: the typo fails to override/undo `.vote-down-off, [...] {cursor: pointer;}` as defined in `all.css`. Nice find indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed in dev, to be deployed later, good catch.

Comment: There's [this similar issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74036/150235), if you're feeling bored one day. :P