# Change "votes" in profile to "votes cast"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

To an outsider, the vote stats section in the profile page:

[image: Vote cast details]

suggests that this is the number of votes *received*.

It's usually not really important, but in a careers context, one wouldn't want a potential employer to see this and think, *"what? The guy got 1500 downvotes?"*

Please clarify the wording to something like

## Votes cast

This has a duplicate [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31850/ui-suggestion-change-votes-on-user-page-to-make-it-clearer-they-are-votes-cast) but the question, and the answers, have derailed into  a discussion about getting downvoted.

Comment: Possibly stupid alternative: "Voting"

Comment: This seems to have been implemented, and will probably show up in the next build. Thanks!

Comment: I see "status-completed" here, which is fine, but I just saw "1 Votes Cast" on my webapps.se profile, which is poor English.

Comment: *hits @PhilipDurbin with a [giant S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/295232)*

Comment: As always, close voters, *don't vote No Repro* if the reason you can't produce the stated preconditions is because of the way the fix was implemented.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When I first started using StackOverflow, the votes section was really confusing, especially the arrows by the numbers even though I saw them next to the answers.  I did not figure it out until I had the rep to vote and realized what it was.  But adding "cast" to the end would really help make it clearer.

Comment: And then until recently the down arrow for the cast up-votes [showed a hand cursor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83335/up-votes-indicator-on-user-profile-page-displays-hand-cursor) while hovering, possibly fooling folks into thinking clicking would have some effect. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the whole ting and think about it you realize that it's only what the user have done. So my suggestion that it might get a headline saying:

### Actions by user

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea as well, but I think "votes" is the only thing where it's really misleading.

Answer (score -2):

As indicated by the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) label, this feature has been implemented.

[image: new votes cast section]

Comment: "As indicated by the [tag:status-completed] label" — well, yes, that's all that's *really* necessary, generally speaking. FRs and bug reports don't actually need an answer when resolved, and if they do get one it should probably explain any unusual reasoning or implementation quirks or limitations.

Comment: [We've been over this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254037/make-tag-page-a-synonym-of-tags-page/295595#comment959051_295595)...